# Impossible to delete table in SAS Enterprise Guide

Tags: datatable, sas, dataset, enterprise-guide

I can't process to deleting my table. I get this error:
"ERROR: File SASUSER.MCO.DATA is not a SAS data set."
I've tried many ways to delete but neither works.
Thanks for felp!

tested with (proc delete / proc sql drop / %deltable )

I have used the bellow codes:

```
proc sql; drop table sasuser.MCO; quit; 
%deltable (tables=sasuser.MCO) 
proc datasets nolist lib=sasuser; delete MCO ; quit;
```

log and result of `proc datasets lib=sasuser; run;`
this is the log:
[here](https://fr.anotepad.com/notes/mbh9g72b)

and the result is [here](https://fr.anotepad.com/notes/kgg9hk44)

Comment: Show the actual code tried.  Show the log for `proc datasets lib=sasuser;
run;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error message it seems that the file is NOT an actual SAS dataset.  I have never seen a SAS dataset on Unix that as only one thousand bytes long, even an empty dataset is normally more like 14K, depending on the default block size that SAS uses to create the files.

So just use the operating system to delete the file.  The name of the file should be mco.sas7bdat and it should be in the directory that the SASUSER libref is pointing to.  So if you have XCMD option active you could just use code like this:

```
x "rm %sysfunc(pathname(sasuser))/mco.sas7bdat";
```

If XCMD is not active then you will need to use the FDELETE() function instead.

Comment: The FDELETE() function did the job.